# How to make folders writable?

Tags: web-server, permissions

I just installed apache2 and wordpress on my RPi.
I followed this [tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/web-server-wordpress/worksheet.md).

But after successful installation, I moved on to customization, but unable to upload any images, etc.

I receive the following,

> Error rit Logo ful…2 - Copy.jpg 
>    Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2015/01. 
>    Is its parent directory writable by the server?

I am unsure of how to proceed. Do I have to change the file permissions to writable or change owner of the directory ?

Please advise on how to overcome this error along with appropriate commands.

Comment: This would fit better on [unix.se] or [webapps.se] - as this issue isn't Raspberry Pi-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you still use the default Apache 2 document root. It was created by root but Apache 2 is running under a different user/group. So you have to chown the folder to the user/group of Apache 2.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

That should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

What Nevil Verdoold say's right. But in order to make a folder writable, you have to give it the correct permissions.

Depending on where is the root folder of Wordpress, I suggest that you set it this way:

```
chmod -R 664 /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: I wouldn't use 664 on a directory. By excluding the executable flag, you won't be able to change into the directory. I'd recommend 775 instead (or simply use "ug+w").

Comment: I've never seen an executable file in this folder and subfolder, but your are right. ug+w. It might be a good idea to remove execution flag from wp-content/uploads/* though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make the comment clear: the executable flag is nothing to do with files in the directory, but the directory itself. If a directory doesn't have execute permissions in UNIX, you can't change into it (you can still list it because of the read bit, but you can't "traverse" it). For example, try "mkdir foo", "chmod -x foo", "cd foo" and you should find you get "permission denied". See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened for more info.